# Making several twitter API post requests quickly

Tags: python, twitter

I've been trying to write an app that will send several  twitter api post requests through the python REQUEST module where time is of the extreme essence. However, as I begin to send more of these requests it takes exponentially longer to process.

I have combed through several other related posts but have been unable to find one that properly suits this issue. I've seen several suggestions of using async or threading but have been rather unsuccessful in implementing it for my purposes because of the requirement of oauth.

A cutout of my code is as follows:

```
import urllib2
import json
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
import httplib2
import requests
from datetime import datetime



print "found?"
found = raw_input()

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json'

def get_oauth():
    oauth = OAuth1("xxxxxxxxx",
                client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                resource_owner_key="xxxxxxxxxx",
                resource_owner_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
    return oauth
def get_oauthfranco():
    oauthfranco = OAuth1("xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                client_secret="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                resource_owner_key="xxxxxxxxxxxx",
                resource_owner_secret="xxxxxxxx")
    return oauthfranco

startTime = datetime.now()



oauth = get_oauth()
oauthf = get_oauthfranco()


requests.post(url, data={'screen_name':'vuoc','text':'hello ppls ' + found}, auth=oauth, stream=True)
requests.post(url, data={'screen_name':'vuoc','text':'hello ppls number 2 ' + found}, auth=oauth)
requests.post(url, data={'screen_name':'vuoc','text':'hello ppls number 3 ' + found}, auth=oauthf, stream=True)
requests.post(url, data={'screen_name':'vuoc','text':'hello ppls number 4 ' + found}, auth=oauthf)
requests.post(url, data={'screen_name':'vuoc','text':'hello ppls number 5 ' + found}, auth=oauths, stream=True)
```

The final product, of course, would contain a lot more than simply 4 post requests (looking to do 20+).

Any suggestions as to how to approach optimizing the speed through threading/async while STILL being able to use oauth are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe it is not your code issue? Are you aware of the throttling (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)?

Comment: I see that it limits more than 15 requests at a time per app. I split my requests between different apps and have never tested with more than 12 Direct Message posts at a time so I don't think that is my issue. Thanks for the response though

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example

concurrent.futures is available as a backport on pypi for older python versions

Comment: Yeah I was looking at this earlier. Maybe I'm missing something but the problem this, as well as the Grequests modules both have is that I dont see how I can have it sent several requests to ONE url. All the examples provided by these two modules both only show their usefulness in sending requests to several DIFFERENT urls.

Comment: Just use URLS = [yoururl] * 50

Comment: Got this to work but it seems like this module only helps with multiple indentical post requests. It does not enhance the speed of several references to the same post url unfortunately :(

Comment: It can do what you need to do. Its just about threading. Since your example is not really complete (no post here too) it's hard to help more